# proving a closed form of recursive function using complete induction

Tags: proof-writing, induction, computer-science

for the following recursive function:
$$
T(n) = \left\{\begin{aligned}
&1 &&: n=1\\
&2T(n/2)+n/2 &&: n>1
\end{aligned}
\right.$$
Note:n is the power of 2
I found the closed form $$n+\frac{n log(n)}{2}$$
I need help with doing the inductive step using the complete induction

Comment: What is the domain of $T$? That recursion only defines values of $n$ that are powers of $2$. For any other $n$, the recursion will not take you down to $1$. If $n$ is supposed to be restricted to powers of $2$, then I highly recomment that you define $S(k) = T(2^k)$, which has recursion $$S(k) = \begin{cases} 1 &: k = 0\\2S(k - 1) + 2^{k-1} &: k > 0\end{cases}$$ Normal induction works on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally found the answer myself. I thought sharing may help others with similar questions.For this question, ***

> assume that all of the logs are base 2.

---

---

### Predicate:

---

P(n):T(n)=$n+\frac{nlog(n)}{2}$ in other words the closed from of this piece wise function is $n+\frac{nlog(n)}{2}$

---

### Base Case:

---

Take the smallest value of n which is 1, T(1)=1=$1+\frac{1log(1)}{2}$ since log(1)=0

---

### Induction Step:

---

Induction Hypothesis: Assume for all $1 \le k < k+1$ that $k+\frac{k log(k)}{2}$ is true.

Now we have to prove that p(k+1) will be true.
T(n)=$2T(\frac{k+1}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}$ since we know that the inputs of function T can be 2,4,8,16,....,$2^n$ this means that $1\le\frac{k+1}{2}\le k$. Therefore according to the induction hypothesis, $T(\frac{k+1}{2})=\frac{k+1}{2}+\frac{\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2})}{2}$.
$$T(n)=2T(\frac{k+1}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}$$$$=2(\frac{k+1}{2}+\frac{\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2})}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}(1)$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2})+\frac{k+1}{2}(log(2))$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{2}log(\frac{k+1}{2}2)$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{k+1}{2}log(k+1)$$
$$=(k+1)+\frac{(k+1)log(k+1)}{2}$$
Therefore, our closed form is correct.